# Unable to delete files in D drive

Tags: windows-10, disk-management

Following is the content of my D-drive. The folder is empty. But when I try to delete them, it says I don't have the permission -

D-drive-contents

[image: D-drive-contents]

message-when-clicked-on-delete

[image: message-when-clicked-on-delete]

I wanted to clear my D-drive so that I could delete it and expand my C drive. But probably because of these folders, I am unable to do it. 
The `delete volume` button in the Disk Management is disabled for some reason.

[image]

[image]

The following is the screenshot of the properties window after selecting bother the `WindowsApps and Program Files` folder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5k66.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure there’s nothing important there? There’s a folder for MS Store apps and a _Program Files_ folder. Also, a page file.

Comment: @DanielB I selected both the folders and clicked on properties the size says 0 bytes. I am attaching the screenshot in the OP. Also, if you see in the Disk Management, the D drive is 99% free.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? You will need to move your page file as well to delete the D drive. Also it is on a different disk so you can't expand your C drive the way you want.

Comment: Your not supposed to be able to delete WindowsApps.  By design not even an Administrator user has permissions to do so, if you want the folder gone, you can always format the drive. However, I don’t recommend you do that, until you verify absolutely none of your UWP applications are stored on that drive.

Comment: @DavidPostill So what I understand is that C drive and D drive have both a physical volume of their own. So neither can they be deleted nor I can ever merge C and D together

Comment: @DavidPostill Yeah, I have tried rebooting. How do I move the page file? Also, since C and D drives are on separate physical volumes, Is there some way the other disk is also used for the C drive. As having a C drive of only 100 GB is causing space issues

Answer (score 0):

Properties only says "0 bytes" because it has no access to the folder
`WindowsApps`.

The disk D actually contains 3.36 GB of data (284.59 - 281.23).

You apparently moved this ultra-important folder from
`C:\Program Files`, as it seems that you ran out of disk-space on C.

You are lucky that you didn't manage to delete these folders, or
Windows would have been badly damaged.

Comment: I probably did move it a long time back. Is it possible to move it back to C if I make some space in the C drive?

Comment: Certainly, in exactly the same way as you did before.

Comment: The `WindowsApps` folder is probably the result of moving apps using the official method (“Move” button in Apps list). Windows offers first-class support for spreading apps across multiple drives after all. Still, there could be anything inside. The Apps list also has a filter function for that purpose.